# ubuntu 12.10 not detecting windows 7

Tags: 12.10

ubuntu 12.10 not detecting windows 7 on sony vaio laptop .My windows is 32 bit and ubuntu is 64 bit. I installed in the same  way in my friend mechine it is working. but my
 windows 7 not detected by ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Your bios doen't detect windows7 os,is that correct?

Comment: my ubuntu installation not detecting. My BIOS does

Comment: did you installed ubuntu on your machine or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) Resize the Win partition to create free space on your HDD. 
You can do it with gparted by choosing "smth else" during Ubuntu install or with a Win partitioning tool such as EaseUS Partition Master. I personally prefer to use Win tools to resize Win partitions, but gparted must work.

2) Choose "smth else" during Ubuntu install, and install Ubuntu on this free space.

3) After installing Ubuntu manually add Windows 7 to your GRUB menu: "sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom", follow instructions here: http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/. Ubuntu has no native GUI GRUB2 editor like KDE's ((

This procedure was considered super-user-friendly in the Mandrake days)

NB Check if you don't already have four primary partitions on your HDD. You won't be able to install Linux unless you delete / change to logical one of these.

NB Backup. Resizing partitions is never risk free, EVEN if Ubuntu install had detected your Win.

Comment: Do i able to access my windows after installing ubuntu, when i try to install it is not recognizing my partitions even it is asking to install ubuntu in entire hard disk in "something else" option. This also erases all my data in my system. I want dual boot and i dont want to lose my data. Please help me.

Comment: click the option something else,and make ubuntu to install on a partition you want.

Comment: After choosing "something else", how does gparted see your hard drive? Just a guess: Ubuntu install may not be able to "install alongside" if you already have 4 primary partitions, which is quite possible for pre-installed Win.